# Hover an element, add class to another

Tags: jquery

I have two lists:

```
<ul id="list1">
   <li class="link1">Link 1</li>
   <li class="link2">Link 2</li>
   <li class="link3">Link 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
   <li class="link1">Link 1</li>
   <li class="link2">Link 2</li>
   <li class="link3">Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want when I hover "link1" from "list1" to add a class (.active) to "link1" from "list2". And same for "list2"... It is possible to make a function, because I have lot of li with same classes, and will be too bad to do it manually for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#list1 li,#list2 li").hover(function() {
    var index =  $(this).index();
    $("#list1, #list2").each(function() {
         $("li",this).eq(index).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/639Jj/1/)

Comment: +1 (especially for the fiddle), and nice approach. Though the OP did specifically talk about classnames, so I wonder whether requiring identical element ordering is still a valid solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your li elements does not have another class than link1, link2 etc. it pretty easy:

```
var list1 = $("#list1"); // Store references to list1 and list2
var list2 = $("#list2");

list1.find("li").hover(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr("class"); // Fetch current class name
    list2.find("li").removeClass("active"); // Remove active class from all items in list2
    list2.find("." + className).addClass("active"); // Find an item with the same class name, but only items thats children of list2 (second parameter), and add class active
});
```

Comment: Yes, but you didn't provide a solution for it ;)

Comment: @Tomalak in my first sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("#list1 .link1").hover(function () {
  $("#list2 .link1").addClass("active");
});
```

or, use $("#list2").find(".link1")...

Comment: "because I have lot of li with same classes, and will be too bad to do it manually for each."

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("li").hover(function () {
  var targetClass = $(this).attr('class');
  $("."+targetClass).not($(this)).addClass("active");
}, function() {
  $("li").removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this even if they don't have the same class

using `$(this).index()` will return the index of current hovered element. So, you just have to add the class to element of same index on the other list

Here's a basic working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wckyq/